# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'full_name')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an error which I'm not sure why I get it... It says that the problem is inside handleSubmit. If the problem is specifically with     `obj.full_name = name;` then why there is no problem with the rest like     `obj.email = email;`
Any help would be appreciated :)

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import JSONDATA from "../data/MOCK_DATA.json";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Edit = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [role, setRole] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  var index = JSONDATA.map((e) => {
    return e.id;
  }).indexOf(id);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let obj = JSONDATA[index];

    obj.full_name = name;
    obj.email = email;
    obj.role = role;
    obj.location = location;

    navigate("/");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setId(localStorage.getItem("id"));
    setName(localStorage.getItem("name"));
    setEmail(localStorage.getItem("email"));
    setRole(localStorage.getItem("role"));
    setLocation(localStorage.getItem("location"));
  }, []);

  //

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[45rem] max-w-[1500px] mx-auto">
      <h1 className="flex justify-center items-center text-3xl pt-[7rem] font-semibold text-orange-600 mx-auto">
        Edit a new listing
      </h1>
      <form
        className="gap-10 flex h-full flex-col mx-auto justify-center items-center"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <input
          className=" bg-gray-200 my-2 px-4 rounded-2xl shadow-xl"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          className=" bg-gray-200 my-2 px-4 rounded-2xl shadow-xl"
          placeholder="Email"
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          className=" bg-gray-200 my-2 px-4 rounded-2xl shadow-xl"
          placeholder="Role"
          type="text"
          id="role"
          name="role"
          value={role}
          onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          className=" bg-gray-200 my-2 px-4 rounded-2xl shadow-xl"
          placeholder="Location"
          type="text"
          id="location"
          name="location"
          value={location}
          onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button
          className="my-2 px-4 py-3 bg-blue-300 active:bg-blue-500 rounded-2xl shadow-xl"
          type="submit"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          Update
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Edit;
```

Comment: *"then why there is no problem with the rest like obj.email = email;"* - How have you confirmed that?  If you remove the line which produces the error and re-test, does the next line not produce the same error?  It seems **extremely likely** that it would and that your assertion may be based on a false assumption.

Comment: Javascript doesn't keep on running when there's an exception thrown. `let obj = JSONDATA[index];` `obj` is undefined, so check that `JSONDATA` has a defined property at `index`. How does your code handle when `localStorage.getItem("id")` is null? Also, remove the `handleSubmit` click hander on the button, the form handles it.

Comment: most likely your JS just stopped when there's an error thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because these lines of code run instantly when the component evaluates for the first time:

```
var index = JSONDATA.map((e) => {
  return e.id;
}).indexOf(id);
```

And the initial `id` is `""` as set by default in useState.
So if `id === ""` then `indexOf("")` is undefined and you're trying to assign values to it. The error occurs only in the first assignment because it throws an error and react is preventing the running of the rest code.

Make sure you run your `useEffect` hook before the `handleSubmit` declaration.
Also to get a proper `index` of your mock data wrap it in `useMemo` like this:

```
const index = useMemo(() => JSONDATA.map((e) => e.id).indexOf(id), [id]);
```

This will be updated when the `id` in state will be changed.

Consider adding some type-safety to your code, because whenever your localStorage data will be unavailable or your mocked data will be empty this `index` could be undefined.
That's why I would add also some conditions in your `let obj` in `handleSubmit` function:

```
// I wrapped also this function in useCallback to make sure the 'index' will be always up to date

const handleSubmit = useCallback(e => {
   e.preventDefault();

   // you can use const as objects are mutable
   const obj = JSONDATA[index] || {}; // this will make sure there will be an object

   obj.full_name = name;
   obj.email = email;
   obj.role = role;
   obj.location = location;

   navigate('/');
}, [index]);
```

Comment: Wow there are no errors now, thanks! But for some reason when I click the submit button and it takes me to the home page, the data doesn't seem to change...

Comment: @AshdodyBoy What data are you expecting to change, and where?

Comment: I have a mock data JSON file that has id, name, email, role, location and changing any of them except the id but in the edit page after I've change the name for example and click submit and redirect back to home age, the name is the same as it was. In the home page, I have this function:

  `const handleEdit = (id, full_name, email, role, location) => {
    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
    localStorage.setItem("full_name", full_name);
    localStorage.setItem("email", email);
    localStorage.setItem("role", role);
    localStorage.setItem("location", location);
  };`

Comment: @AshdodyBoy Whatever it is that you are trying to update in your UI code should probably be part of *some* React state somewhere, and properly updated instead of mutated. I'm also pretty sure mutating `obj` isn't mutating the file contents of `MOCK_DATA.json`.

Comment: Yeah, mutatin json file will not work. You have to add this object to the react stream.
The bad but easy use is to add this as an object and export from main file (app.js).
Then mutate exactly this object.
Or use React.Context for much better approach and convention of global state